# WHERE NOT clause for incomming relationship not working in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database where two users attempt to trade a number of cards.
Each trade node has two outgoing relationships towards the two users the trade involves, 
and the cards that are being traded.
If no agreement is made, a subsequent trade is created pointing to the previous one with a `PREVIOUS` relationship.
If an agreement is made the last node of the trade chain is marked with a `success:true` property.

[image]

The image below represents an example trade between two users.

I am trying to get all last trade nodes between two users with ids 10 and 20.
The last trade node is the one that has no incoming relationship.

My attempt is this:

```
MATCH (u:User)<--(t:Trade)-->(n:User)
WHERE (ID(u)=10 AND ID(n)=20) OR (ID(u)=20 AND ID(n)=10) 
AND NOT (t)<-[:PREVIOUS]-()
RETURN t
```

The above however returns all 3 trade nodes. In fact the third line seems to make no 
difference in the result of the query.

Why is that? How else can I achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the order of boolean evaluations.

That is, AND is evaluated before OR (but after parenthesis), so what you have (simplified down) is:

`WHERE (<id check 1>) OR (<id check 2>) AND <not pattern>`

The AND grouping gets evaluated first, so it behaves like:

`WHERE (<id check 1>) OR ((<id check 2>) AND <not pattern>)`

so as long as the first id check evaluates to true, then the entire WHERE clause comes out as true.

To fix, add parenthesis to surround the ID predicates like so:

```
WHERE ((ID(u)=10 AND ID(n)=20) OR (ID(u)=20 AND ID(n)=10))
AND NOT (t)<-[:PREVIOUS]-()
```

Comment: Tis what it is.

Comment: Simplified my explanation a bit.